# Serializing custom Spring Integration MessageSources that produce lists of messages

Tags: spring-integration

Java 11 and Spring Integration 5.x here. I am trying to create a custom `MessageSource<Widget>` that can be applied to an integration flow like so:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow(WidgetMessageSource widgetMessageSource) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(widgetMessageSource)                 
        .get();
}
```

This `WidgetMessageSource` queries a remote system and fetches `Widget` instances that I then need to produce `Message<Widget>` with, and place them on my flow:

```
public class WidgetMessageSource implements MessageSource<Widget> {
    
    @Override
    public Message<Widget> receive() {

        List<Widget> widgets = fetchStagedWidgets();
        // How to produce a List<Message<Widget>> and not just a Message<Widget>???

    }

    private List<Widget> fetchStagedWidgets() {
        // connect to remote system and pull down 0+ widgets
        return where_the_magic_happens(); // TODO
    }

}
```

My problem is, when `fetchStagedWidgets` is called, 0+ `Widget` instances will be returned. If no `Widget` instances are fetched, then nothing should happen (no messages are placed on the flow).

But if `Widget` instances are fetched, I need each `Widget` to appear in its own `Message<Widget>`. So I have a cardinality mismatch between what will happen when `fetchStagedWidgets` is called and what the `MessageSource` API expects (1 message per call).

What are my options here? The only thing I can think of is serializing what is sitting behind the `fetchStagedWidgets` call so that it will only ever return 0 or 1 `Widget` instances, but there's actually quite a lot of complexity (services + infrastructure) required to get `fetchStagedWidgets` to behave that way. Any other options here, using the `MessageSource` API or some other facility within Spring Integration? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring Integration (and messaging at all), it doesn't matter what payload you have in the message: the infrastructure which dispatches messages might look into headers, but in most cases doesn't care about the payload.

So, you are free to have a single message with a `List` as payload to return over there. You can produce something like `Message<List<Message<Widget>>>`, but does it really make sense and give any advantages over `Message<List<Widget>>`? Why would one wrap every item in the list into its individual message?

We have a sample in the framework for DB-specific message sources. For example, `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`. It does return a `List` mapped records. Same happens with a `R2dbcMessageSource`, which produces a `Flux` of mapped record.

You probably need to look into a `.split()` to deal with a `List<Widget>` payload downstream.

Technically I also don't see a reason in the custom `MessageSource`. The plain `Supplier<List<Widget>>` will fit into your current requirements to call that `fetchStagedWidgets()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the steering @Artem (+1). In your mind when should `IntegrationFlows.from(MessageSource)` be used versus `IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(Supplier)`? Does the supplier option offer any tangible benefits in my case?

Comment: No, in the end the `Supplier` is wrapped into a `MessageSource`. Just only the way to let you avoid Spring Integration API in your services. The `MessageSource` makes sense mostly for out-of-the-box channel adapters. End-users usually are just fine with their POJO style configuration.

Comment: Hey @Artem, last followup regarding suppliers, apologies. So I am now leaning towards the `Supplier<List<Widget>>`-based approach and then follow it with a Splitter to split out each `Widget` into its own message. However I do need to be able to set headers on each message. Meaning: I need to split out the `List<Widget>` provided by the Supplier into a list of `Message<Widget>` where the `Widget` is the payload and where I can set headers on each message individually. After the Splitter, how would I wrap each split `Widget` into a `Message<Widget>` (so that I can set headers on it)?

Comment: For that purpose look into the `enrichHeaders()` after `split()`. To be precise the framework always wrap the result of your method into a `Message`. So, even you think that splitter just returns every `Widget` in that list, it also wrapped into a message. It is not a splitter responsibility to add extra headers, so, the special endpoint has to be used: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/message-transformation.html#header-enricher